# How to focus on text field when user clicked on a disabled href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website which I had done to disable href when user status are pending. I not allow them to proceed to other page unless they done to fill in details and press on submit button. Now I want to be when user clicked on those disabled link and system will direct focus the cursor to particular field. How to I do that?

This is my JavaScript code :

```
$(function(){
    if(<{$status}> === 2){
        $("a").on("click", function(){return false;});
    }
})
```

This is my HTML text field that I want to focus :

```
<li class="profile-details-label">Name *</li>
<li><input name="name" type="text" value="<{$getMemberInfoById[thisrsa].name}>"/></li>
```

I hope I can get some help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are <{$status}> and <{$getMemberInfoById[thisrsa].name}> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){

    $("a").on("click", function(){
        if(<{$status}> === 2){
            $("input[type='text']").focus(); //OR $("input[name='name']").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            //do some action...
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)** in click handler of a.

> .focus():Bind an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```
$("input[name=name]").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
 $("a").on("click", function(){
    if(<{$status}> === 2){
        document.getElementsByName('name')[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
   ...
});
```